# Is there a faster way of to generate the required output than using a one-to-many join in Proc SQL?

Tags: join, optimization, sas, one-to-many

I require an output that shows the total number of hours worked in a rolling 24 hour window. The data is currently stored such that each row is one hourly slot (for example 7-8am on Jan 2nd) per person and how much they worked in that hour stored as "Hour". What I need to create is another field that is the sum of the most recent 24 hourly slots (inclusive) for each row. So for the 7-8am example above I would want the sum of "Hour" across the 24 rows: Jan 1st 8-9am, Jan 1st 9-10am... Jan 2nd 6-7am, Jan 2nd 7-8am.

Rinse and repeat for each hourly slot.

There are 6000 people, and we have 6 months of data, which means the table has 6000 * 183 days * 24 hours = 26.3m rows.

I am currently done this using the code below, which works on a sample of 50 people very easily, but grinds to a halt when I try it on the full table, somewhat understandably.

Does anyone have any other ideas? All date/time variables are in datetime format.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
 select x.*
 , case when Hours_Wrkd_In_Window > 16 then 1 else 0 end as Correct 
 from (
  select a.ID
  , a.Start_DTTM
  , a.End_DTTM
  , sum(b.hours) as Hours_Wrkd_In_Window
  from have a
   left join have b
   on a.ID = b.ID
   and b.start_dttm > a.start_dttm - (24 * 60 * 60)
   and b.start_dttm <= a.start_dttm
  where datepart(a.Start_dttm) >= &report_start_date.
  and datepart(a.Start_dttm) < &report_end_date.
  group by ID
  , a.Start_DTTM
  , a.End_DTTM  
) x
order by x.ID
, x.Start_DTTM
;quit;
```

Comment: I Suspect this join is your problem - left join have b
   on a.ID = b.ID
   and b.start_dttm > a.start_dttm - (24 * 60 * 60)

Comment: Are the `start_dt` and `end_dt` values the hour slots and are they always correct ? and presumably each `hours` is in the range of [0..1] ?

Comment: @richard - yes, they are the hourly slot's start and end time, so on a specific row it would have a start_dttm of  01JUN2018:00:00:00 and end_dttm of  01JUN2018:01:00:00

Yes, they are always correct and there is one for every hour within the window per person. 

Yes, hours is in the range [0..1]

Comment: @jimmy8ball - Yup, I'm sure it's that as well. Was hoping someone would have an alternative way to calculate this that would run faster!

Comment: A clue would be to calculate this section in the select and then filter in your where clause - i.e. SELECT a.start_dttm - (24 * 60 * 60) AS [Calcultaed Field Name] - Also as stated in the answer below, having an index on the commonly filtered fields will go some way to optimising your query.

Comment: @jimmy8ball - Thanks for following up. Could you be a little bit more specific? 

I'm afraid I can't see a way of getting the outcome I desire by calculating the start_dttm - (24*60*60) section in the SELECT then using a WHERE to filter it out? If I put that as a subquery for the left join, which is what I think you mean, then I can't see how that will work?

Comment: Are you open to a data step solution rather than using proc sql? This could be done in a single pass of the dataset using arrays and lag/retain/DOW-loop.

Comment: Hi @user667489 - I'm open to any and all suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most performant `DATA` step solution most likely involves a ring-array to track the 1hr time slots and hours worked within.  The ring will allow a rolling aggregate (sum and count) to be computed based on what goes into and out of the ring.

If you have a wide SAS license, look into the procedures in SAS/ETS (Econometrics and Time Series). Proc EXPAND might have some rolling aggregate capability.

This sample DATA Step code took <10s (WORK folder on SSD) to run on simulated data for 6k people with 6months of complete coverage of 1hr time slots.

```
data have(keep=id start_dt end_dt hours);
  do id = 1 to 6000;

    do start_dt 
     = intnx('dtmonth', datetime(), -12)
    to intnx('dtmonth', datetime(), -6)
    by dhms(0,1,0,0)
    ;
      end_dt = start_dt + dhms(0,1,0,0);

      hours = 0.25 * floor (5 * ranuni(123)); * 0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4 or 1 hour;

      output;
    end;
  end;

  format hours 5.2;
run;

/* %let log= ; options obs=50 linesize=200; * submit this (instead of next) if you want to log the logic; */

%let log=*; options obs=max;

data want2(keep=id start_dt end_dt hours hours_rolling_sum hours_rolling_cnt hours_out_:);

  array dt_ring(24) _temporary_;
  array hr_ring(24) _temporary_;

  call missing (of dt_ring(*));
  call missing (of hr_ring(*));

  if 0 then set have; * prep pdv column order;

  hours_rolling_sum = 0;
  hours_rolling_cnt = 0;
  label hours_rolling_sum = 'Hours worked in prior 24 hours';

  index = 0;

  do until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id start_dt;

    index + 1;
    if index > 24 then index = 1;

    hours_out_sum = 0;
    hours_out_cnt = 0;

    do clear = 1 by 1 until (clear=0);

      if sum (dt_ring(index), 0) = 0 then do;
        * index is first go through ring array, or hit a zeroed slot;

&log putlog 'NOTE: ' index= 'clear for empty ring item. ';

        clear = 0;
      end;
      else
      if start_dt - dt_ring(index) >= %sysfunc(dhms(0,24,0,0)) then do;

&log putlog / 'NOTE: ' index= 'reducting and zeroing.' /;

        hours_out_sum + hr_ring(index);
        hours_out_cnt + 1;

        hours_rolling_sum = hours_rolling_sum - hr_ring(index);
        hours_rolling_cnt = hours_rolling_cnt - 1;
        dt_ring(index) = 0;
        hr_ring(index) = 0;

        * advance item to next item, that might also be more than 24 hours ago;
        index = index + 1;
        if index > 24 then index = 1;

      end;
      else do;

&log putlog / 'NOTE: ' index= 'back off !' /;

        * index was advanced to an item within 24 hours, back off one;
        index = index - 1;
        if index < 1 then index = 24;
        clear = 0;
      end;

    end; /* do clear */

    dt_ring(index) = start_dt;
    hr_ring(index) = hours;

    hours_rolling_sum + hours;
    hours_rolling_cnt + 1;

&log putlog 'NOTE: ' index= 'overlaying and aggregating.' / 'NOTE:  ' start_dt= hours= hours_rolling_sum= hours_rolling_cnt=;

    output;
  end; /* do until */

  format hours_rolling_sum 5.2 hours_rolling_cnt 2.; 
  format hours_out_sum 5.2 hours_out_cnt 2.;
run;

options obs=max;
```

When reviewing the results you should notice the delta for hours_rolling_sum is +(hours in slot) - (hours_out_sum{which is hrs removed from ring})

If you must use SQL, I would suggest following @jspascal and index the table, but rearrange the query to left join original data to inner-joined subselect (so that SQL will do an index involved hash join on the ids) . For same amount of few people it should faster than original query, but still be too slow for doing all 6K.

```
proc sql; 
  create index id on have;
  create index id_slot on have (id, start_dt);
quit;

proc sql _method;

  reset inobs=50; * limit data so you can see the _method;

  create table want as
  select
    have.*
  , case 
      when ROLLING.HOURS_WORKED_24_HOUR_PRIOR > 16 
      then 1 
      else 0
    end as REVIEW_TIME_CLOCKING_FLAG

  from 
    have
  left join
  (
    select
        EACH_SLOT.id
      , EACH_SLOT.start_dt
      , count(*) as SLOT_COUNT_24_HOUR_PRIOR
      , sum(PRIOR_SLOT.hours) as HOURS_WORKED_24_HOUR_PRIOR
      from 
        have as EACH_SLOT
      join
        have as PRIOR_SLOT
      on
        EACH_SLOT.ID = PRIOR_SLOT.ID
        and EACH_SLOT.start_dt - PRIOR_SLOT.start_dt between 0 and %sysfunc(dhms(0,24,0,0))-0.1
      group by
        EACH_SLOT.id, EACH_SLOT.start_dt
    ) as ROLLING

    on
      have.ID = ROLLING.ID
      and have.start_dt = ROLLING.start_dt

    order by
        id, start_dt
    ;

  %put NOTE: SQLOOPS = &SQLOOPS;
quit;
```

The inner join is pyramid-like and still involves a lot of internal looping.

Comment: Hi @Richard, thank you so much for this. The code works amazingly! I knew there would be a better way, but while I have used arrays before I'm not very familiar with them and so wasn't sure how really to start.

Comment: There is a lot going on in the code feature-wise and it could take a 'newbie' a day or two to unravel.  Also, welcome to Stackoverflow (SO) -- be sure to review the SO help center such as https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

A compound index on the columns being accessed in the joined table - `id` + `start_dttm` + `hours` - would be useful if there isn't one already.

Using `msglevel=i` will print some diagnostics about how the query is executed. It may give some additional hints.

Comment: Hi @jspcal Would it be possible for you to explain how to utilise this index in the above? I have created the compound index using a proc datasets statement, but I'm not quite sure where/how this would be used in the my code?

thanks